# iterate over arbitrary count of pivot fields

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have several VBA scripts that iterate over Pivot Items within a Pivot Field, but I would like to be able to use them regardless of the number of fields that are there. How can I do this?

For example, I may have at some time two row fields (e.g. {a b c d} for row field one and {A B} for row field two. How can I iterate through all possible combinations of the current fields? This would mean that I would get {aA aB bA bB cA cB dA dB}. However, the solution should be flexible so that if I had four fields (e.g. {a b} {A B} {1 2} {! @}) or six (which I can't easily visualize) I could get all combinations thereof (e.g. {aA1! aA1@ aA2! ... bB1@ bB2! bB2@}.

Ideally, the solution would not just give me the set of strings that indicates each of the names, but something that I can execute as it iterates through the set.

I can imagine a slightly complicated setup where I have an array of indices, a do-loop, a function that increments the array of indices, and a function that checks whether or not the terminal counts have been reached. Is there a better way? Also, would the only way I can use this be via worksheet functions?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question :) Hope I have understood your query correctly :P

Let's say we have a pivot like this?

[image]

So if you want the results like this

aaaA

aaaB

aaaC

aaaD

bbbA

bbbB

bbbC

bbbD

cccA

cccB

cccC

cccD

dddA

dddB

dddC

dddD

A1

A2

A3

A4

B1

B2

B3

B4

C1

C2

C3

C4

D1

D2

D3

D4

Then you can use this code. This sample outputs the data into Col G (In this Case). You will have to change it in case you have more than 6 Pivot Fields.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim pvtItem As PivotItem
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, LastRowNC As Long

    '~~> Set ws to sheet which has the relevant pivot table
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    '~~> Add a temp sheet for output
    Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add

    j = 0

    '~~> Loop through all pivot fields in the relevant pivot
    '~~> Change "PivotTable1" to the relevant pivot table name
    For Each pvtField In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields
        i = 1
        j = j + 1
        For Each pvtItem In pvtField.PivotItems
            '~~> Output the Pivot items in a temp sheet
            With wsTemp
                .Cells(i, j).Value = pvtItem.Value
                i = i + 1
            End With
        Next
    Next

    '~~> Get the lastrow in the temp sheet
    LastRow = wsTemp.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wsTemp.[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    '~~> Get the lastcol in the temp sheet
    LastCol = wsTemp.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wsTemp.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    m = 1: j = 0

    '~~> Create the necessary combinations
    With wsTemp
        For i = 1 To LastCol
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(1, i + 1) <> "" Then
                LastRowNC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row
                For k = 1 To LastRow
                    For l = 1 To LastRowNC
                        '~~> Output combinations in Col G
                        '~~> You will have to change this if you have
                        '~~> more than 6 pivot fields
                        .Range("G" & m).Value = .Cells(k, i) & .Cells(l, i + 1)
                        m = m + 1
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you wanted? If not then do let me know and I will amend it.

Sample workbook can be downloaded from [here](http://wikisend.com/download/825002/Book1.xlsm). This link will be live for 7 days.

HTH

Sid

Comment: Thanks for your time, but sorry, no, this was not what I was looking for. A) It should only combine the fields that are currently in the Pivot Table. B) Your code does not produce all combinations, as it seems to combine the two fields (current and next pivot field). C) The reference .PivotFields seems to regard the data value as a pivot field, which isn't ideal.